# Help java if statement

Tags: java, html

I'm currently working on a project using the current if statement and i'm sure i'm making a mistake could anyone help?

```
if ("receiveInput" != null){
        HTML.clickHtmlLink(objBrowser, ".text", "receiveInput",1);
    }
    else if ("receiveSyncIt..." != null) {
        HTML.clickHtmlLink(objBrowser, ".text", "receiveSyncIt...",1);
    }
    else if ("ReceiveQueryI..." != null) {
        HTML.clickHtmlLink(objBrowser, ".text", "ReceiveQueryI...",1);
    }
    else {
        HTML.clickHtmlLink(objBrowser, ".text", "ReceiveWF_EVE...",1);
    }
```

Comment: "receiveInput" is a string... guess you wanted to compare a variable with null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're interested in HTML, I'm guessing that those are keys into a parameter map.  So maybe your code needs to look like this:

```
// request is the incoming HTTP request
if (request.getParameter("receiveInput") != null){
        HTML.clickHtmlLink(objBrowser, ".text", "receiveInput",1);
    }
    else if (request.getParameter("receiveSyncIt...") != null) {
        HTML.clickHtmlLink(objBrowser, ".text", "receiveSyncIt...",1);
    }
    else if (request.getParameter("ReceiveQueryI...") != null) {
        HTML.clickHtmlLink(objBrowser, ".text", "ReceiveQueryI...",1);
    }
    else {
        HTML.clickHtmlLink(objBrowser, ".text", "ReceiveWF_EVE...",1);
    }
```

All those other smart people who told you to use `equals` instead of `==` to compare Strings are spot on, but that's not your issue here.

Answer (score 5):

`"receiveInput" != null` and all other conditions are always true. so it will always take the first path. You should have something along the lines

```
if (var.equals("somestring"))
{
...
}
else if (var.equals("someOtherString"))
{
...
}
```

Comment: `if (var.equals("someString"))` assuming `var` is a `String`

Answer (score 3):

If receiveInput is a variable do not wrap in quotes. Doing so makes it a string and a string is never null.

Answer (score 2):

"receiveInput" != null is always true. That's a static string. Do you mean to have a container.get("receiveInput")?

Answer (score 0):

If that is your code line for line then you issue is that the strings will never be null, they are hard coded strings.